# Excel Download from ASP.net page

Tags: vb.net, excel, download

I am very fairly new to web programming. I am attempting to download an excel from an ASP.net website. IT does not need authentication, however I am unable to debug the URL as firebug would just not how me the request URL. Searched high and low. Any inputs on this will be awesome. Thank you in advance.

Website: http://tebb.elpaso.com/ebbmasterpage/Capacity/OperAvailAutoTable.aspx?code=TGP&name=Operationally%20Available%20Capacity&status=Cap&sParam2=M&sParam3=5/4/2012&sParam8=S

Actions: I click "Summary Download" button to download the excel.

I have no idea where the onClick() goes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Download the Excel file from within Excel, or from somewhere else? As it is right now, the question is too vague to answer.

Comment: -The link above has an option to download the data in Excel format. I want to programatically download the excel using VB.Net. My issue is that I cannot find the exact URL to get to the excel. Looking at the page source it seems he is doing some postbacks and stuff but I am not too familiar with javascript (or ASP.net). Al I want to do is download that excel from within a VB.net program. I have tried setting the cookie for the request and posting etc but none of those usual conventional logic work. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this page have the same data as a direct download? Seems like it would be easier to start from there... http://tebb.elpaso.com/ebbmasterpage/Downloads/Downloads.aspx?code=TGP&status=Downloads&name=Downloads

Comment: No, I tried that. It goes to the page once again. It wont go to the direct link for the excel. For example there is not such link as http://www.xyz.com/myExcel.xlsThe download link still goes to the page where there is a data table with all the info AND a button called "Summary Download" which lets me download an excel. Now, my challenge is -  I cannot get to the URL that "Summary Download" gets to in the background.

Comment: Any clue? I am still struggling to find the URL? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's no way to do this other than automating IE to submit the page.  No direct URL to the download, because it requires a form submission.  Kind of a cmplex page, so would take more effort than I can give right now.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it is complex. Would anyone know of any good site that ill explain how to automate IE in VB.net. I have done it as a macro but when I converted that to VB.net it gives me some HRESULT error.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is slightly complex. Not the First part but the Second part.

**Logic**

**PART 1**) Click the "Summary Download" button to launch the "File Download" dialog

**PART 2**) Click the Save button in the "File Download" to finally save the file

---

**PART 1**

Place a WebBrowser1 Control and a Button on your form. Paste this code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://tebb.elpaso.com/ebbmasterpage/Capacity/OperAvailAutoTable.aspx?code=TGP&name=Operationally%20Available%20Capacity&status=Cap&sParam2=M&sParam3=5/4/2012&sParam8=S")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As  _
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> 4 Then Exit Sub

    Dim el As HtmlElement = _
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_sumBtnDownload")

    el.InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

Now when you run this code, it will Click on the button "Summary Download" and launch the File Download Dialog box. See snapshot below.

---

**PART 2 - The complex Part**

Now you need to use API's to click on the `Save` button on the `File Download` dialog box. Fortunately, I have covered this in my blog so you won't have any problems :)

**Topic: VBA/VB.Net/VB6–Click Open/Save/Cancel Button on IE Download window – PART I**

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/

**Snapshot**

[image]

HTH

Comment: Ah! But, that is really not what I wanted. The deal is, I am setting this up as a cron job to run every 30 minutes on windows task scheduler. So, I cannot do it from my own form. What I was trying to achieve was from within IE itself.  Here is my code (and of course it does not work)

Dim ie  as object
 ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.visible = True
 ie.navigate(strURL)
 Do Until ie.ReadyState = "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
  Loop
 ie.document.forms(1).submit()
 ie.Document.all("ctl00$WebSplitter1$tmpl1$ContentPlaceHolder1$sumBtnDownload").Click()

Comment: You can still create an exe and instead of calling it from the button, call it from the form load event :) That ways it will work with windows task scheduler.

Comment: Another way would be to go about writing a console application and using the above code :)

Comment: It never seems to get into the Webbrowser1 code. I did make sure it was called Webbrowser1. When I click the button it loads the page fine and then it exits the code.

Answer (score 1):

http://tebb.elpaso.com/ebbmasterpage/Capacity/OperAvailAutoTable.aspx?code=TGP&name=Operationally+Available+Capacity&status=Cap&sParam2=M&sParam3=5%2f4%2f2012&sParam8=S

Param3 represents the date, %2f is a html encoded /

The key here is the post data.
To download the excel file the raw post data is:

__*EVENTTARGET=&*_EVENTARGUMENT=&ctl00_WebSplitter1_tmpl0_NavigationUserControl1_TreeView1_ExpandState=ennunnnnnnnnunnnnnunnnnnnunnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnunnnunnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnunnnnnnnn&ctl00_WebSplitter1_tmpl0_NavigationUserControl1_TreeView1_SelectedNode=&_*LASTFOCUS=&*_VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUIOTA0MDgxNzEPFgYeCmhpZGVDb2x1bW4y3QEAAQAAAP%2F%2F%2F%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%2F%2F%2F%2F%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%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%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%2BQFPcGVyQXZhaWxBdXRvVGFibGUuYXNweD9jb2RlPVRHUCZuYW1lPU9wZXJhdGlvbmFsbHkgQXZhaWxhYmxlIENhcGFjaXR5JnN0YXR1cz1DYXAmc1BhcmFtMT1UR1Amc1BhcmFtMj1EJnNQYXJhbTM9MDUvMDQvMjAxMiAwOTowMCZzUGFyYW00PVAwMDEwOCZzUGFyYW01PTAwMTc3NyZzUGFyYW02PU1MViA1MjkgLyBZc2Nsb3NrZXkgUGxhbnQgKFUvUyBTTSkmc1BhcmFtNz1NYXkgIDQgMjAxMiAgOTo0NlBNJnNQYXJhbTg9RCZkZXRhaWxzPVlkZAIKD2QWAgIBDw8WAh8nBfcBT3BlckF2YWlsQXV0b1RhYmxlLmFzcHg%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%2FY29kZT1UR1AmbmFtZT1PcGVyYXRpb25hbGx5IEF2YWlsYWJsZSBDYXBhY2l0eSZzdGF0dXM9Q2FwJnNQYXJhbTE9VEdQJnNQYXJhbTI9RCZzUGFyYW0zPTA1LzA0LzIwMTIgMDk6MDAmc1BhcmFtND1QMDAwNTMmc1BhcmFtNT0wMDE3NDcmc1BhcmFtNj1TVEEgMDE3IChVL1MgU00pJnNQYXJhbTc9TWF5ICA0IDIwMTIgIDk6NDZQTSZzUGFyYW04PUQmZGV0YWlscz1ZZGQCAg8UKwACZDwrABwBABYEHxNkHxFkZAIDDxYCHgJkTgUiT3BlcmF0aW9uYWxseUF2YWlsYWJsZUNhcGFjaXR5LlhMU2QCBA8UKwACFgIeDERvd25sb2FkTmFtZQUeT3BlcmF0aW9uYWxseUF2YWlsYWJsZUNhcGFjaXR5ZGQCCQ8WAh4FVmFsdWUFgwFNYXN0ZXJTdHlsZVNoZWV0LmNzc3wuLi9pZ19yZXMvRWxlY3RyaWNCbHVlL2lnX3NwbGl0dGVyLmNzc3wuLi9pZ19yZXMvRWxlY3RyaWNCbHVlL2lnX3NoYXJlZC5jc3N8Li4vaWdfcmVzL0VsZWN0cmljQmx1ZS9pZ19ncmlkLmNzc2QYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgMFEmN0bDAwJFdlYlNwbGl0dGVyMQU5Y3RsMDAkV2ViU3BsaXR0ZXIxJHRtcGwwJE5hdmlnYXRpb25Vc2VyQ29udHJvbDEkVHJlZVZpZXcxBTpjdGwwMCRXZWJTcGxpdHRlcjEkdG1wbDEkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRVbHRyYVdlYkdyaWQxChBz9pI6%2BnL7w6b%2B8VpMMVQUpjRuWt1dkDI5QOKOHqk%3D&__PREVIOUSPAGE=*q1Vu5vuap4CxPC3AZarvFeTSUmpu1Y5Qe6RAgsXMl*-9eN-hzR45dQjqjC-HEjZ0&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDwKF0M%2FIBQKWk6OhBAKx%2FMC2DgLM5d7LCALhg%2FaUDwKHxPzXAQKkobflCwKtsbmoAQLQ5oWgCgL73d1IAvSyi6UMAvayt6UMAvCyt6UMAoaSk6MKAqDJoG0zZk9itnjKzHvp455sJC0LF3pnU%2F9GwKhhL5KKketXYQ%3D%3D&ctl00_WebSplitter1_clientState=%7C0%7C216%2C2%2C1058%2C2%2C%7C%7C%5B%5B%5B%5Bnull%2Cnull%5D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%7B%220%22%3A%5B%5Bnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C2%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%2217%25%22%5D%5D%2C%221%22%3A%5B%5Bnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%2283%25%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%5D%2C%5B%7B%7D%2C%5B%7B%222%22%3A%5B%221%22%2C10%2C%221058px%22%5D%2C%223%22%3A%5B%220%22%2C10%2C%22216px%22%5D%7D%5D%5D%2Cnull%5D&ctl00%24WebSplitter1%24tmpl1%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24sumBtnDownload=Summary+Download&ctl00%24WebSplitter1%24tmpl1%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24SumDownloadDDL=EXCEL&ctl00%24WebSplitter1%24tmpl1%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24PageSizeDDL=15&ctl00xWebSplitter1xtmpl1xContentPlaceHolder1xUltraWebGrid1=%253CDisplayLayout%253E%253CStateChanges%253E%253C%2FStateChanges%253E%253C%2FDisplayLayout%253E&ctl00%24_IG_CSS_LINKS_=MasterStyleSheet.css%7C..%2Fig_res%2FElectricBlue%2Fig_splitter.css%7C..%2Fig_res%2FElectricBlue%2Fig_shared.css%7C..%2Fig_res%2FElectricBlue%2Fig_grid.css

This was discovered using HTTP Analyzer v6. I made a VB6 test program that I successful downloaded 5/4/2012, 5/3/2012, and 5/2/2012 simply by changing the Param3 in the URL, it uses cURL, but you should be able to use it as an example of how to submit the http request to recieve the excel file as the http response. The LoadResString(101), loads the above post data into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Equivalently, LoadResString could be replaced with a string literal of the above post data.

```
Private Sub XPButton1_Click()
Dim CurlContext As Long
Dim buf As New StringBuffer

CurlContext = vbcurl_easy_init()

vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tebb.elpaso.com/ebbmasterpage/Capacity/OperAvailAutoTable.aspx?code=TGP&name=Operationally+Available+Capacity&status=Cap&sParam2=M&sParam3=5%2f3%2f2012&sParam8=S"
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, App.Path & "\cookie.txt"
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, App.Path & "\cookie.txt"
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1

vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_POST, 1
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, LoadResString(101)


vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY 'the next 5 lines are only needed to accommodate connecting through a proxy server
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0 
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_PROXY, "your.proxy.if.any.com"
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80 'or your proxy port
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "" 
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ObjPtr(buf)
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, _
    AddressOf WriteFunction
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, _
    AddressOf DebugFunction
vbcurl_easy_setopt CurlContext, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, True

ret = vbcurl_easy_perform(CurlContext)

Open App.Path & "\test.xls" For Output As #1
Print #1, buf.stringData
Close #1

End Sub
```

This is the direct way to download the data, using Siddharth Rout's route would be resilient to code changes of the website. One final note on the 'complex part'. All you need to do is use FindWindow to wait for the "File Download" box to appear, once you know it is up, you can use `keybd_event` to send 3 tabs and an enter key, wait a second, press enter again and "y" if you will be overwriting files. Now, the advantage to the direct download is that you can choose exactly where and how to save it.

If you would like to know more about the particulars of my method, I would be glad to post the code to StringBuffer, WriteFunction, and DebugFunction and explain how to reference libcurl from vb.

Update, additonal code per request:
[StringBuffer.cls](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72374458/StringBuffer.cls)

```
Private byteData() As Byte
Private stringLength As Long
Private arrayLength As Long


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

ReDim byteData(1024)
arrayLength = 1024
stringLength = 0

End Sub

Public Sub Class_Terminate()

Erase byteData

End Sub


Public Property Get stringData() As String

stringData = String(stringLength, " ")
CopyMemory ByVal stringData, byteData(0), stringLength

End Property

Public Property Let stringData(newStringdata As String)

Dim newStringLength As Long

newStringLength = Len(newStringdata)

If newStringLength > arrayLength Then
    arrayLength = (arrayLength + (newStringLength - newStringLength Mod 2)) * 2
    ReDim Preserve byteData(arrayLength)
End If


CopyMemory byteData(0), ByVal newStringdata, newStringLength

stringLength = newStringLength


End Property

Public Function quickConcat(newStringdata As String)

Dim newStringLength As Long

newStringLength = Len(newStringdata) + stringLength

If newStringLength > arrayLength Then
    arrayLength = (arrayLength + (newStringLength - newStringLength Mod 2)) * 2
    ReDim Preserve byteData(arrayLength)
End If

Dim amountToAdd
amountToAdd = newStringLength - stringLength

CopyMemory byteData(stringLength), ByVal newStringdata, amountToAdd

stringLength = newStringLength

End Function
```

[WriteFunction:](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72374458/WriteDebug.bas)

```
Public Function WriteFunction(ByVal rawBytes As Long, _
    ByVal sz As Long, ByVal nmemb As Long, _
    ByVal extra As Long) As Long

    Dim totalBytes As Long, i As Long
    Dim obj As Object, buf As StringBuffer
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim Buffer() As Byte

    totalBytes = sz * nmemb

    Set obj = AsObject(extra)
    Set buf = obj
    ' append the binary characters to the HTML string
    If Not ((rawBytes = 0) Or (totalBytes = 0)) Then

        ReDim Buffer(0 To (totalBytes - 1)) As Byte
        CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal rawBytes, totalBytes

        tempStr = String(totalBytes, " ")
        CopyMemory ByVal tempStr, Buffer(0), totalBytes

        buf.quickConcat (tempStr)

    End If
    ' Need this line below since AsObject gets a stolen reference
    ObjectPtr(obj) = 0&

    ' Return value
    WriteFunction = totalBytes
End Function
```

[DebugFunction:](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72374458/WriteDebug.bas)

```
Public Function DebugFunction(ByVal info As curl_infotype, _
    ByVal rawBytes As Long, ByVal numBytes As Long, _
    ByVal extra As Long) As Long
    Dim debugMsg As String
    Dim i As Long
    debugMsg = ""
    For i = 0 To numBytes - 1
        debugMsg = debugMsg & Chr(MemByte(rawBytes + i))
    Next
    Debug.Print "info=" & info & ", debugMsg=" & debugMsg
    DebugFunction = 0

    DoEvents

End Function
```

And here are the dll and type libraries required to use curl in vb6:
[libcurl bindings for vb6](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72374458/vbcurl.zip)

unpack the above file to the project directory and go to project->references and add both the tlb files (type libraries).

Also, here is the sourceforge page for the vb libcurl bindings, the download includes source and several examples: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-vb/

Comment: I like this only slightly better because I am more familiar with cURL than VB (I opted for VB only because the older program was in VB). Can you post your code please? Will be real helpful.

Comment: this uses libcurl for vb, can you use libcurl? 

Of course, this can be adapted to use with curl.exe command line utility, if you are more familiar with it. I updated the answer to include the missing parts of the vb code, that implements the write and debug functions and how vb6 reference libcurl.dll